# How to install windows 11 with 'TPM' and 'secure boot' errors on Inspiron 5570?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have Dell Inspiron 5570 with processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U. Whenever I try to install windows 11, it shows an error of 'TPM' and 'secure boot'. I have 'PTT' instead of 'TPM' in my laptop and for enabling 'secure boot' in my laptop I am asked to first disable 'legacy boot'. I when I do so, my laptop is unable to boot. If anyone with such laptop has been able to install windows 11, kindly guide me too. P.S: I have tried all the bypass 'TPM' and 'secure boot' hacks available on internet, none worked.

[PTT requires Legacy Boot to be disabled for getting enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utOSV.jpg)

[Secure Boot requires Legacy Boot to be disabled for getting enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4rfb.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to boot a USB stick or an already-installed OS?

Comment: Is the drive you want to install onto using GPT (good) or MBR (you might have to convert it to GPT)?

Comment: @user1686 I tried to boot, usb, hdd, and sdd. none worked.

Comment: @FaisalJamilKhan: How did you create the bootable USB stick? (Are you sure it was created to be EFI-compatible? In some tools you have to specifically select that option.) Can you still boot the HDD if you switch back to legacy/BIOS mode?

Comment: @AndrewMorton drive is using MBR.

Comment: @user1686 I burned windows ISO into USB using RUFUS. I can not boot when I disable legacy boot.

Comment: @FaisalJamilKhan: Okay, so you need to convert the HDD to GPT/UEFI, _and_ tell Rufus to create a USB for GPT/UEFI.

Comment: @FaisalJamilKhan Is there anything already on the disk that you want to install Windows 11 onto?

Answer (score 0):

PTT is Intel’s firmware technique of Platform Trust Technology (PTT), which Windows 11 should accept as the equivalent of TPM.

The Inspiron 5570 is in Dell's list of
[Dell computers tested for upgrade to Windows 11](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000187485/dell-computers-tested-for-upgrade-to-windows-11).

In addition, the Intel Core i5-8250U is in Microsoft's list of
[Windows 11 supported Intel processors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-intel-processors).

This means that your computer should support Windows 11 and the
installation should succeed.

The indicated errors of "TPM" and "Secure boot" are probably to be
addressed in the BIOS. Boot into it using the hotkey that is
indicated during the boot, and enable the items related to these
two terms (you might be looking for PTT rather than TPM).

If you can't find these, take a shot of the BIOS screens and include
them in your post, for us to have a look.

Comment: **kindly check the images attached.**

Comment: Why is the BIOS/UEFI in Legacy Mode? Windows 11 cannot boot in this mode.

Comment: If I disable legacy boot then, My PC does not find any disk to boot from. No disk is displayed in the bootable devices list then.

Comment: Is your disk in MBR format? Non-legacy boot requires GPT. If that's the case, beware - most converters to GPT will also erase all data on the disk.

Comment: then I guess the drive on which I have my windows10 installed is in MBR format and for installing windows11, I will need to convert it to GPT, but how to do so?

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/389971/how-to-move-an-existing-installation-of-window-7-64bit-to-uefi-from-legacy), but take full backups before doing it (and not with Microsoft's Backup). This is a dangerous operation.

Comment: @harrymc The two times I have used [MBR2GPT.EXE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) it has run without incident (backup taken beforehand, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

> I burned windows ISO into USB using RUFUS. I can not boot when I disable legacy boot.

In Rufus, you need to specifically select UEFI/GPT as the system type. While the original ISO was compatible with both, Rufus deliberately generates USB sticks that only work with one mode *or* the other.

Rufus-created Windows USB sticks may still be incompatible with Secure Boot, but it should be fine to disable it for installation and re-enable it later.

There are also [other ways](https://superuser.com/a/1547818/1686) to create a Windows 10 USB stick that *are* compatible with Secure Boot.

> drive is using MBR

Then Windows was installed for BIOS boot mode – you need to convert the disk to GPT and the system to UEFI boot mode. Recent Windows 10 versions have a `mbr2gpt` tool which you can use to convert an already-installed Windows system from BIOS/MBR to UEFI/GPT without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

**Dell Inspiron 5570** supports windows 11 as its in the list of [*Dell computers tested for upgrade to Windows 11*](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-pk/000187485/dell-computers-tested-for-upgrade-to-windows-11) and **Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U** also supports windows 11 as its in the list of [*Windows 11 supported Intel processors*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-intel-processors), but if the drive in the laptop on which windows 11 is to be installed, is using MBR partition table format then first it needs to be switched to GPT partition table format. Then enable 'PTT security' and 'secure boot' in BIOS. After these steps windows 11, will get installed without any error.